# permutation $\pi$, type, permutation $\sigma^4 = \pi$

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Permutation $ \pi$ has a signature $2^43^5$. Find number of permutation $\sigma$ such that $\sigma^4 = \pi$

Could you give me a clue ?

Comment: I am not sure if your notation for signature is a general one... can you just define what do you mean when you say signature?

Comment: There are four cycles lenght of 2, and five cycles length of 3, rest of cycles are lenght of 1

Comment: The number will depend on the cardinality of the underlying set (which is 23 plus the number of cycles of length 1).

Comment: so Is there solution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Consider the primes $2, 3$ separately.

What is the fourth power of a $3$-cycle?

Now note that for the $2$-cycle (transposition) bit, if you square a transposition, you will get the identity. When you square this fourth power, you get the identity in the $2$ bit of your element. Can you think of a kind of permutation which would have that property? Can you find a permutation of that kind whose fourth power is a product of four transpositions?

Comment: fourh power of 3-cycle is the same 3-cycle.  fourth power of 6-cycle yields twice 3-cycle

Comment: So can you see how to get the part of the fourth root $\sigma$ which gives you the $3^5$ part of $\pi$?

Comment: It may be: two 6-cycles + one 3-cycle or  5 *3-cycle+0*6-cycle or 3 * 3-cycle+1*6-cycle

Comment: @xawey Now you need to sort out the other part of the problem.

Comment: Ok, but when can I get 2-cycles ? It must be cycle of length 8 ?

Comment: @xawey you can add as many $2$-cycles and $4$-cycles as you like (they vanish on taking the fourth power) and note that the fourth power of a $12-cycle$ will be the product of four $3$-cycles. But the essential observation to unlock the problem is that you need an element of order $8$ for the fourth power to have order $2$.

Comment: I don't think about orders (it seems to me group theory :( )   Yeah, (1) when lenght is 4k, then fourth power give four k-cycles. (2) When lenght is 2k, then ourth power give two k-cycles.  (3) When length is 2k+1, then fourth power give one (2k+1)-cycle. Ok ???

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16982/discussion-between-xawey-and-mark-bennet).